# cannot get debugging to work for wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I was having a problem getting my application to step into my service. It is running locally to be able to test. I checked the box "Enable Unmanaged Code Debugging" and that let me step into it but now I'm getting this message:

[image]

My application that is calling the service and the application are both in the same solution.

How do I enable debugging so that I can see why I'm getting an error?

**UPDATE #1**

I changed my default browser to IE and I got this message:

```
Locating source for 'S:\Source\Web Projects\TruckApps\TruckService\TruckService\TruckService.svc.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {8a b6 a0 5e 2b d2 81 2c 52 bf 54 64 e1 85 53 f6}
Determining whether the checksum matches for the following locations:
1: S:\Source\Web Projects\TruckApps\TruckService\TruckService\TruckService.svc.cs Checksum: MD5 {c4 50 5b 92 f7 49 fd 8c 66 ba b3 44 89 6c 25 de} Checksum doesn't match.
The file 'S:\Source\Web Projects\TruckApps\TruckService\TruckService\TruckService.svc.cs' exists.
Looking in script documents for 'S:\Source\Web Projects\TruckApps\TruckService\TruckService\TruckService.svc.cs'...
Determining whether the checksum matches for the following locations:
1: S:\Source\Web Projects\TruckApps\TruckService\TruckService\TruckService.svc.cs Checksum: MD5 {c4 50 5b 92 f7 49 fd 8c 66 ba b3 44 89 6c 25 de} Checksum doesn't match.
Looking in the projects for 'S:\Source\Web Projects\TruckApps\TruckService\TruckService\TruckService.svc.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
Looking in directory 'S:\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: S:\Source\Web Projects\TruckApps\TruckService\TruckService\TruckService.svc.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'S:\Source\Web Projects\TruckApps\TruckService\TruckService\TruckService.svc.cs'.
```

**UPDATE 2**

I did what Damith said I got this message now:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.
```

Comment: Did you host the service at local IIS? Looks like a cache problem, where the version hosted is diferent from the current! Try to stop the service, stop, clean the solution and try again!

Comment: I'm using the Visual Studio dev server. I cleaned the solution and rebuilt and no luck.

Comment: Close VS, stop all WebServer40.exe processes, go to solution folder and manually delete all obj and bin files, open VS again and rebuild.build the project again and run both service and the client app at ones on debug mode. put break point on service method and test.

Comment: Try running VS in administrator mode.

Comment: @Damith I added an update in reply to what you said to do.

Comment: @Kash I always run in administrative mode since I have to run from the c:\program files directory.

Comment: @ErocM one more thing to do, can you remove the service reference and add it again and see?

Comment: When you are performing a clean make sure that the temp files in the Temp ASP.NET\.. folder are deleted. Also make sure that if you have another project added as reference it is included in the build configuration